# pymorph2 ошибка при запуске

Tags: python, pymorphy2

```
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 224, in init
    self._init_units(units)
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 235, in _init_units
    self._units.append((self._bound_unit(unit), False))
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\analyzer.py", line 246, in _bound_unit
    unit = unit.clone()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 35, in clone
    return self.class(**self._get_params())
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 76, in _get_params
    (key, getattr(self, key, None)) for key in self._get_param_names()
                                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\linch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pymorphy2\units\base.py", line 70, in _get_param_names
    args, varargs, kw, default = inspect.getargspec(cls.init)
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'inspect' has no attribute 'getargspec'. Did you mean: 'getargs'?
```

Код ошибки, что с этим делать?

Comment: Установить более старый питон